# Using RadioBoxes to multiply a value then display that value in a textbox

Tags: c#

I need some help, I'm trying to multiply a value using check boxes the code is below, if you need any more information let me know:

```cs
if (rdOne.Checked)
{ 
    subTotal * 1;
}
if (rdTwo.Checked)
{
    subTotal * 2;
}
if (rdThree.Checked)
{
    subTotal * 3;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `subTotal = subTotal * 2;` (which can also be written as `subTotal *= 2;`)? Note, you might want to use `else if` instead of the second and third `if`s.

Comment: @41686d6564 thank you i could figure it out to save my life